# The meaning of "caper"

Tags: meaning-in-context

The following paragraph is a review on "Ocean's 8". What is the meaning of "[caper](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ocean%27s_8)" in this context?

"The website's critical consensus reads, "Ocean's 8 isn't quite as smooth as its predecessors, but still has enough cast chemistry and flair to enjoyably lift the price of a ticket from filmgoers up for an undemanding caper."

According to Cambridge Dictionary, "caper" means 1. an illegal, unusual, or entertaining activity. 2. a small, dark green flower bud that is used as an ingredient to give a slightly sour taste to food.

However, it seems "caper" in this context means something else. Thank you.

Comment: [1.] is good: an undemanding entertaining activity.

Comment: Try Door Number 1, emphasis on *illegal*..

Comment: Caper refers here both to the storyline of the film and the experience of watching it. Still. one thinks of veal piccata.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In discussion of stories, a caper means a group of criminals committing an elaborate crime.  Breaking into a high-security place to steal something, for instance.

Comment: Exactly. In Oceans 8, eight women steal jewelry at a museum in an elaborate and comical scheme.

Comment: Thank you for your explanations! Now that I have leaned the definition of "caper" in this context, I have one more question: The website's critical consensus calls the caper "undemanding"? Is it because the criminals in the story are not patient enough and don't have the required skills and attention to pull a perfect job? Thank you once again!